# Delphi 7 New Application crashes when Step Into (recently) with access violation

Tags: windows-7, delphi

I am running Delphi 7 on Windows 7 Professional. Recently the following error started happening:

I start Delphi, which comes up with a default new application.  I then save this empty application with no code other than the default. If I run the application (f9) all is fine. 
However, if I use Trace Into (f7) the program crashes with an access violation error on the first line of code after begin. "Application.initialize.

I have added nothing!  The program does run when I execute it with f9.  It and other programs stop or crash whenever I try and use the Step Into f7.

The error is :

*Project Project3.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0044C4C0 in module Project3.exe'  Write of address 0044C4C0'*

I have uninstalled Delphi and reinstalled it in its own directory off Root/Delphi7.  Still the same error occurs.

Any help would be great!

Regards, 
Arnold

```
program Project3;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize; //This is where it crashes. 

  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully got Delphi 7 installed and working on Windows 8.1. This may not be relevant for Windows 7, but I tested a simple application as you suggest and I can trace into fine. I set the Delphi 7 application compatibility as follows:

- Windows XP (Service Pack 3) = ON

Settings as follows:

- Disable display scaling on high DPI settings = ON
- Run this program as an administrator = ON